# Why is the interest on EUR so much lower than USD?

Tags: interest, interactive-brokers

https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/accounts/fees/pricing-interest-rates.php

4.330% vs 2.245%

Difference isn't explained by the inflation difference

Comment: Supply vs demand?

Comment: Central banks play a huge role in this.  The European Central Bank has been slower to raise interest rates than the US Federal Reserve.  As of March, the fed funds rate was at 4.5% compared with 3% for the ECB.  Since banks can easily borrow at these rates, they're unlikely to ever offer a higher rate to customers for deposits.

Comment: So 4.5-4.330 vs 3-2.245 should be kind of the metric to explain this? If so EUR is trying very hard to be competitive but it just can't?

Answer (score 3):

Because the central banks said so. As of writing, the USA's Federal Funds Rate (which is the interbank rate target) is "4.75% to 5.00%" while the ECB deposit rate is 3.00% and fixed rate tenders rate is 3.50% (these are not exactly equivalent to the fed funds rate, but kinda similar, since the interbank rate is necessarily in the middle).

According to [interest rate parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interest_rate_parity), we should expect the difference to correspond to a shift in exchange rates - about 1.5%-2% per year in the euro's favour. In other words, although you will get more interest if you save your money in dollars, the dollars become worth less (or the euros become worth more) so it evens out - *if nothing changes*.

Comment: Is this usually accurate or is it similar to stock predictions? "we should expect the difference to correspond to a shift in exchange rates"

Comment: @user3722246 the FX movement is caused by something called the carry trade - banks borrowing in the lower interest rate currency to receive interest in the higher rate country at a profit equal to the spread. This moves the FX rates through supply and demand as normal

Comment: @user3722246 I understand it's an expectation in the mathematical sense of the average outcome and also the sense that it might not happen if something else causes it to change (such as european rates going up until they match american rates). I understand it's correct if you use today's prediction of what the EUR/USD rate will be in a year, but many things could happen that would make the prediction wrong.

Comment: Interest parity usually does not hold (if it would, the carry trade mentioned in a comment by MD-Tech would be impossible). You can read a lot of details [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/67940/54838). Generally, short term interest rates are predominantly influenced by the central banks.

Comment: @AKdemy well, generally such parities *nearly* hold, as they get almost to the point where banks stop bothering to do the corresponding arbitrage. If it doesn't hold at all, does that mean any sane individual must sell their euros and buy dollars and put them in dollar banks to earn interest? does this not force the exchange rate to conform to interest rate parity?

Comment: Interest rate parity is rejected in almost all empirical studies. In other words, the exchange rate almost never confirms with interest rate parity. Also not on modern economics models which feature overshooting.  If you know it doesn't hold, it still doesn't tell you what direction the FX rate goes. Frequently, the carry trade works for a while. Trading desk have a saying though:"With the carry trade you go up the stairs and down the elevator".

Comment: @AKdemy so what can answer my question then? Any ideas?

Comment: @xqwxeqwex, You actual question is answered here in my opinion. It's the central banks decision what the interest rate levels in countries are. What happens to exchange rates is a separate question really and answered in the link I provided above.

Comment: It seems obvious that if interest rates are higher in dollars, everyone should withdraw all their euros from their euro bank accounts, exchange them to dollars and put them in dollar bank accounts. I added the bit about interest rate parity to say why they might not do that.